# Why do different objects of the same class show similar results? and what is the way out?

Tags: python, class, object

my code is:

```
class Cereal:
    def __init__(self,name,brand,fiber):
        Cereal.name=name
        Cereal.brand=brand
        Cereal.fiber=fiber
    def __str__(self):
        return "{} cereal is produced by {} and has {} grams of fiber in every serving!".format(Cereal.name,Cereal.brand,Cereal.fiber)

c1=Cereal("Corn Flakes","Kellog's",2)
c2=Cereal("Honey Nut Cheerios","General Mills",3)
print(c1)
print(c2)
```

The output is:

```
Honey Nut Cheerios cereal is produced by General Mills and has 3 grams of fiber in every serving!
Honey Nut Cheerios cereal is produced by General Mills and has 3 grams of fiber in every serving!
```

I want to know how to create 2 container for 2 objects. If you could state the reason that would be a great help.
Thanks

Comment: You need to use `self` in `__init__`, not `Cereal`

Comment: Isn't that a constructer. It will initialize as soon as the  class is called .right?@TedKleinBergman

Comment: I got you @TedKleinBergman .Thanks

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html

Answer (score 2):

Your lines:

```
Cereal.name=name
Cereal.brand=brand
Cereal.fiber=fiber
```

should instead be:

```
self.name=name
self.brand=brand
self.fiber=fiber
```

`self` refers to the current instance of the `Cereal` class. `Cereal` refers to the class itself.

As pointed out by @wjandrea, you also need to change the arguments you pass to `format` from `Cereal.xxx` to `self.xxx`.

Comment: as well `.format(Cereal.name,Cereal.brand,Cereal.fiber)` needs to be fixed in `__str__()`

Comment: oh. My bad .. Thank you sir @wjandrea

Comment: @wjandrea Do you know what `Cereal.name = ...` actually *does* do?

Comment: @SUDIPTASAMAL oh, I was talking to Josh. Thank him, not me! :) I only added a little to what he said.

Comment: @JoshClark Yeah, it assigns a class attribute instead of an instance attribute.

Comment: I am confused. Btw can you tell me what is `Cereal.name` means?

Comment: @wjandrea Thanks! I didn't know you could do that.

Comment: @SUDIPTASAMAL `Cereal.name = 'Chex'` creates a "class attribute." What this means is that you don't need an instance of `Cereal` to get this information. With an instance attribute, you need an instance of the class (e.g., `cheerios = Cereal(...)`, `print(cheerios.brand)`). With a class attribute, you can simply define the class (including the attribute's value) and retrieve the attribute's value (e.g., `print(Cereal.name)` (in my example, this shows `'Chex'`).

Comment: @SUDIPTASAMAL No prob! If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the check mark. This helps keep the focus on older questions which still don't have answers.